# Split two words into variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, split

I have this date/2 word parsed from the database randomly:

```
JAN 2012
FEB 2013
MAR 2014
```

etc.

I want to make the month in variable **a** and the year in variable **b**.
The date is parsed in a span as such:

```
<span class="rt_item">DEC 2012</span>
```

Comment: split it by space and you will get the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
var regex = /([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{4})/;
var matches = "JAN 2012".match(regex);
var a = matches[1];
var b = matches[2];
```

Otherwise, use `.split(" ")`:

```
var matches = "JAN 2012".split(" ");
var a = matches[0];
var b = matches[1];
```

Both methods demonstrated in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YPud/)**.

Comment: The matches could be any 3 letter Month and 4 number year?

Comment: @jQuerybeast Yes. Technically this would match "ZZZ 0000" as well. If you'd like, I can refine to match only English months and years.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object /([A-Z]{3}) ([0-9]{4})/ has no method 'match'

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code since that error was in there. Just copy my edited code (`"JAN 2012".match(regex)`). ;)

Comment: The split doesnt return the [2], to the date. It returns undefined

Comment: `.split()` uses indices `0` and `1`. The regex uses indices `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 10):

Try this  code:

```
    var str="DEC 2012";
    var mon=str.substr(0,3);
    var year=str.substr(4,7);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var mySplitResult = "MAR 2014".split(" ");
var x = mySplitResult[0];
var y = mySplitResult[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create an array of objects containing a (month) and b (year) properties, derived from the span(s):

```
var md = [],
    rtitems = $('.rt_item');
for (var i=0;i<rtitems.length;i+1){
  var item = rtitems[i].text().split(' ');
  md.push ({a: item[0], b: item[1]});
}
```

for a set of spans like:

```
<span class="rt_item">DEC 2012</span>
<span class="rt_item">JAN 2012</span>
<span class="rt_item">FEB 2013</span>
```

`md[0].a` would be `'DEC'`, and `md[0].b` `2012`

Comment: Thank you. This wouldnt help in my situation as I have only 1 span at all times, but it will def be helpful in the near future.